# Cannot use mutating member on immutable value when struct extension returns mutated self

Tags: swift, struct

I have extended Apple's URLRequest struct:

```
extension URLRequest {

    mutating func addJSONContentTypeHeader() -> URLRequest {
      setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

      return self
    }

    mutating func addAuthHeader(withT t: String) -> URLRequest {
      setValue(t, forHTTPHeaderField: "Auth")

      return self
    }
}
```

I can use those methods without issues like e.g.:

```
[...]
return urlRequest.addJSONContentTypeHeader()
```

However, a builder-like pattern like in the follwing example is not possible and returns the error message from the title:

```
return urlRequest.addJSONContentTypeHeader().addAuthHeader(withT: token) <--- error:
```

> Function call returns immutable value.

However, I did mark the extension methods as "mutating". The only way to circumvent this is creating intermediate members:

```
let mutableRequest = urlRequest.addJSONContentTypeHeader()
return mutableRequest.addAuthHeader(withT: token)
```

However, it's certainly not as elegant as the builder pattern one line solution. Why won't swiftc allow me to write it in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's quite obvious because if you have looked at [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest) then you can see that `URLRequest` is a `struct` with initializer of `URL` which is also `struct` leads to return an immutable copy of the original request. `mutating` means your are modifying the calling object but it won't return "mutable" object back!

This is the reason why it gives error. Well, still if you wish to use the same way then I have a modified version of your code.

```
extension URLRequest {

    func addJSONContentTypeHeader() -> URLRequest {
        var newRequest = self
        newRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        return newRequest
    }

    func addAuthHeader(withT t: String) -> URLRequest {
        var newRequest = self
        newRequest.setValue(t, forHTTPHeaderField: "Auth")
        return newRequest
    }
}
```

> Usage:

```
request.addJSONContentTypeHeader().addAuthHeader(withT: "adfakljdhfkjah")
```